# Rails 3.1 SWF file not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason, the new asset pipeline is not pulling in my swf file, which I need.  I've tried placing the swf file in app/assets/, app/assets/flash (after adding  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/flash" to application.rb), public/, public/assets/, vendor/assets/, vendor/assets/flash/, etc…

Any ideas?

view:

```
<%= asset_path('flash/swfupload.swf') %>
```

…becomes /assets/flash/swfupload.swf in the source code; this matches the current path that I'm using.

Comment: asset_path(), is that a custom helper method?? Can you access the Flash file with a direct link in your browser?

Comment: Also, try this: `config/environment/development.rb` : `config.assets.digest = true` change this to `false` and see if it works

Comment: Thanks; asset_path is new to rails 3.1, I've tried linking directly as well but will try the 2nd suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  For some reason, I had to resort to putting the SWF file in public/flash/swfupload.swf. The image that the swf file relied upon wasn't loading but wouldn't show as missing due to not using Flash debug mode.  This made the SWF not load all the way.  I had to call the image with the asset_path, which is expected. Thanks for the help, though.